# Wait for CORS cookie to be set before location.href redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, browser, cross-domain

I'm trying to make a login that persists across more than one domain (that I control). My strategy is, after a successful login response, I send out a CORS request to get a cookie for each of the other required domains. On return of the cookies, I redirect to the users' homepage (which may be on any of the domains)

I am finding that everything works if I comment out the redirect: all the CORS cookies are set, and I am logged in at the other domains. However, when I redirect, the CORS cookies are sometimes not set. Here is the general idea of my code on the client side:

```
    // This is running client side when the user visits "A.com/index.html"
    // PLEASE NOTE: the distinction between A.com and B.com is important

     $.post('https://A.com/attemptLogin', function(data) {
        if (!data.success) { return; }
        var token = data.loginToken;
        var userURL = data.userURL; // userURL may be in A.com or B.com...
        // now get a cookie at the alternate domain B.com
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://B.com/getDomainCookie/' + token,
            method: 'GET',
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            success: function() {
                // if I comment out the next line, the cookie is always set successfully
                // if I leave the line in, it is hit or miss whether the cookie is set.
                location.href = userURL;
            }
        });
    });
```

My guess is that the ajax callback is triggered before the browser is finished setting the cookie, possibly related to the fact that it is a B.com cookie, and this code is running on A.com.

Any help is appreciated. This is my first question posted, so constructive criticism on question ettiquette and formatting is also appreciated!

Comment: Just to be clear, the GET request to `'http://B.com/getDomainCookie/' + token` should set the cookie and then return? If this is what you want then I think that your problem is on the B side, where an asynchronous functions sets the cookie and return a response. Is it possible?

Comment: @cventr, yes, the GET to B.com is purely to set the cookie. The return consists only of an OK response, and the cookie for the B.com domain. As for an async on the B side, I'm not sure what you mean... I control the server at the other end of B.com/getDomainCookie, and it definitely returns the response I want.

Comment: Ok, I can't see what is on the B side so I'm just trying to guess: are you sure you return the response just after that cookies are set? Because maybe the function that you use is asynchronous and the response is returned before it actually set the cookies

Comment: @cventr, I feel like that's not it because the cookie is always set if I stay on the page. But just to be thorough, I can tell you that the (node express style ) endpoint behind /getDomainCookie ends with two lines like this: `res.cookie('name', 'value'); return res.send(200);` literally one line after the other, so the cookie should always be set.

Comment: Can you not test on side B if the cookie was written successfully before return the 200 status?

Answer (score 0):

I put in a 50 ms delay `window.setTimeout(function() { location.href='';}, 50);` Gives it a little idle time to stash to cookie. On another note, doesn't seem to work at all in incognito window, ditches all the CORS cookies.